# Froala - get HTML

Tags: javascript, html, froala

I'm trying to get the current HTML from an element using Froala 2.4
My main reason is to be able to compare the original HTML from the new HTML to see if the user has changed anything, and if that case trigger a save-event.

Here's my current code

```
console.log($(this).froalaEditor('html.get'))    
console.log($(this).data('froala.editor')._original_html);
```

And here's the output

```
<p spellcheck="false">TestString<b>Edited</b></p>
TestString<b>Original</b>
```

The problem is that I want to only retrieve this from the first outout:

```
 TestString<b>Edited</b>
```

*(I don't want the Paragraph-tag to be included, in this example)*

I could make a short function to take care of that for me, but it seems like I'm missing something really obvious regarding the way I get the string from Froala.

Help really appreciated!

Comment: I have updated my answer supposing you need to get rid only of top-level `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to store the contents of your editor somewhere:

```
var html = $(this).froalaEditor('html.get'); // <p spellcheck="false">TestStringEdited</p>
```

And then just strip out HTML tags, if I got you right. The simplest way is [jQuery .text() method](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2):

```
var text = $( html ).text(); // TestStringEdited
```

**update**

You need to strip only upper-level `<p>` tags right? Here is a function that implements filtering that tags with help of jQuery. But you can rewrite it and make an array of exclusion tags, or call it recursively on each child element of content. And also, you can use regular expressions as an alternative.

```
function stripParagraphs( html ) {
  var r = '';

  $( html ).each(function() {

    // test each higher-level tag to be <p>
    if ($( this ).prop( 'tagName' ) === 'P') {
      r += $( this ).html(); // add contents of <p> to result

    } else {
      r += this.outerHTML; // add the whole element to result
    }
  })

  return r;
}
```

[Live example](http://codepen.io/pitetsky/pen/RovrJe?editors=1111).

**one more update**

Strip all top-level tags.

```
function stripTopLevelTags( html ) {
  var r = '';
  $( html ).each( function() {
    r += $( this ).unwrap().html();
  });
  return r;
}
```

[Live example](http://codepen.io/pitetsky/pen/eBxZEV?editors=1111)

Comment: That is a working alternative for this situation in particular, I'll edit the question a bit in a minute! I still need it to be HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will stick with it for now, (It is not always a p-tag), I updated it to one row using this: alert($(html).first().remove().html());  I'll accept your answer in a few hours unless a better solution comes up! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tompina well, that line doesn't work for more than one top-level elements but you know better :) Good luck!